# why my code not run in react-native code in web

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, web

I have a react-native project which is running in Android and iOS perfectly, I know that a react-native app can run on both platform Mobile and Web. So how can I run my current code on Web or how can I convert the current mobile app to the web app.

I have already installed react-dom, react-native-web but I am not getting any success.

Comment: as you said, react-native-web is the best way to turn your app into web. 
If it doesn't work (errors or something else, in that case please show us what errors you are getting), you should check on reactJS

Answer (score 1):

Where did you read that React Native runs Web Apps?

React Native is a framework that only is used to build Mobile Apps.

Probably you are confusing React Native with ReactJS.

I leave you here what is React JS and how to get started, it is so similar to React Native, it won't be so difficult to understand for you if you use React Native.

https://reactjs.org/

Comment: Then what is `npm run web` for? My package.json `scripts.web` is set to `expo start --web`, which I would think ports the JSX to run in a browser. Right?