# ReactNative Code not running on WEB (ReactCLI)

Tags: react-native

I am new to ReactNative world,
I am using ReactCLI (No Expo)

My Code running fine on Android Simulator, but don't know why it is not executing on WEB. (See attachment). I am using Windows 10.

Additionally,
I got URL ([why my code not run in react-native code in web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57413989/why-my-code-not-run-in-react-native-code-in-web/57414810#57414810?newreg=0b025d61b52747699db1aad378ba3d58)) that saying - It doesn't work. But as per the FACEBOOK guideline "*React Native is used to develop applications for **Android, iOS, Web** and UWP by enabling developers to use React along with native platform capabilities.*"

So, what I am missing??

Below is my Package.JSON

```
"scripts": {
    "android": "npx react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "npx react-native start --reset-cache",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "build-android": "cd ./android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "lint"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: IF you use only React Native I guess you cant expect to run it on the web by default... with Expo its a lot easier

Comment: Any idea, How can I Run on Web (ReactCLI - No Expo)

Comment: No just google it - i am always using expo because it is way easier and pretty much can do everything that rn can